# IP camera - Reading live ASF video stream

Tags: video, camera, ffmpeg

I'm trying to read a video stream from an IP camera and store it on disk as several sequential files in MP4 format. I'm using Debian 7.5 with ffmpeg 2.2.

Let's assume the camera DNS name is *webcam* and, the user account / password is *account* / *password*

## Input

the camera input stream is

```
ffprobe http://account:password@webcam/videostream.asf

Input #0, asf, from 'http://account:password@webcam/videostream.asf':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 32 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (MJPG / 0x47504A4D), yuvj422p(pc), 640x480, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: adpcm_ima_wav ([17][0][0][0] / 0x0011), 8000 Hz, 1 channels, s16p, 32 kb/s
```

### ffmpeg conversion

This command opens the output file but doesn't read / write anything.

```
ffmpeg -y -i http://account:password@webcam/videostream.asf -t 30 -c:v libx264 -c:a libfdk_aac -f mp4 ~/output.mp4
```

The process completes successfully and writes 1.1M to the output file.

### Issue

When I open the ~/output.mp4 video (in totem), no image is displayed but a gray background but the progess bar moves forward until the end of the video.

Any idea ?

for reminder I also would like to save data to a disk file which upon a predefined amount of time should rotate to another output file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It works by adding -pix_fmt yuv420p as you mentioned rogerdpack. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `-pix_fmt yuv420p` [your player can't handle the default which is yuv444p]